# Rstudio上でRnwファイルからのpdfレポートの生成

Tags: r, latex

Rstudio上でRnwファイルからのpdfレポートの生成をしたいと思っています。
環境はWin8.1、texは美文書入門のDVDからインストールしたTex Liveです。
Useful Rのドキュメント・プレゼンテーション生成を参考に進めていますがうまくいかないです。
うまくいかない点があるので質問させていただきます。

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
hogehoge
\end{document}
```

というRnwファイルから、Rコンソール上で

```
library(knitr)
setwd("C:\\Users\\hoge\\")
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "lualatex")
knit2pdf("hoge.Rnw",compiler = "lualatex")
```

としたのですが、Compile PDFのボタンを押してもknit2pdfを使ってもエラーになってしまいます。

```
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
unable to run 'lualatex' on 'hoge.tex'
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"lualatex" -interaction=nonstopmode "hoge.tex"' had status 1
```

Texworksで同じソースのものをjsarticleでコンパイルするとうまくいくのですが、上記のものですとPDFが一応生成され、,,graphicxとだけ1ページめに出現、2ページ目以降は正常なものが生成されました。

また、lualatexとplatexの違いってなんなんでしょう？
platexで実行すると

```
this file needs format platex2e
```

というエラーが出て断念しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

は

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

に変更してください．
`dvipdfmx` というのはパッケージの名前ではないので，`\usepackage{}` は間違いです．
`graphicx` パッケージを使う際にはオプションで

```
\usepackage[ドライバ名]{graphicx}
```

というようにドライバ名を指定しますが，この場合は不要です（https://texwiki.texjp.org/?graphicx を参照）．

あとは，

```
knit2pdf("hoge.Rnw",compiler = "lualatex", texi2dvi="lualatex")
```

というようにして実行するか，Compile PDF ボタンを押すとPDFが生成されると思います．

`knit2pdf()` は `texi2pdf()` を呼び出しています．`texi2dvi="lualatex"` という引数は`texi2pdf()`に渡す引数で，「texファイルからpdfを作るのに何を使うか」を指定するものです（詳しくは help を参照）．

`platex`， `lualatex` はTeXの処理系の種類です．
今回の場合は`lualatex`用の`.Rnw`ファイルなので，

```
lualatex hoge.tex
```

とすれば PDF が生成されます．

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

や

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
```

ではうまく行かず、

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{}
```

だとうまくいくようです。
ただまだ原因などまとまっていないので取り急ぎ。